# How to Store the highscore in the game

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game in xcode using cocos2d-x. I want to display the highscore in game over scene.when i run the game, score is displaying in the game over scene instead of highscore, even if the score is less than highscore. I think highscore is not stored. I am using the following code. Please help me to solve this.

```
CCUserDefault *def=CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault();
long int high_score=0; 
if(score>high_score)
{
    def->setIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE, score);
    //def->flush();
    //high_score=def->getIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE);
}
else if(score<high_score)
{
    def->setIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE, high_score);
    //def->flush();
    //high_score=def->getIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE);
}
high_score=def->getIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE);

char s[7];
sprintf(s,"%ld", high_score);
CCLabelTTF *high_label=CCLabelTTF::create(s, "Arial.fnt", 20);
high_label->setPosition(ccp(winwsize - 800, winhsize - 50));
this->addChild(high_label,2);
```

Comment: So `high_score` is always initialized with 0? Maybe make it static or use a member instead of a local variable. ;)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment, I declare the high_score variable as a class member and i delete the score<high_score condition.Now it stores the high scores, But If i stops the build and re-run the code it not displaying the previous high score. It stores the High score again.Please help me to sort this problem.

Comment: That has only to do with variables indirectly. You have to save the value in a file or database. Maybe create a txt file, save the score and read it when you start the program and save the value in the file when you exit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `high_core` variable global.

Pay attention that if `score<high_score` nothing is really needed so you can drop the `def->setIntegerForKey(HIHG_SCORE, high_score);` statement.

Comment: Don't make it global! Make it a class member. But not a global, that's bad style.

Comment: indeed if there is OOP design here, better to have it a class member... that what i meant by defining a "global"... meant, not local on the stack

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment, I declare the high_score variable as a class member and i delete the score<high_score condition.Now it stores the high scores, But If i stops the build and re-run the code it not displaying the previous high score. It stores the High score again.Please help me to sort this problem.

Comment: @user3616535: if you want to save the high score between program sessions you have to store it upon end of one session into some buffer (file or registry), then you need to re-load it back to memory in the second session

Comment: now it is working I added the "high_score=def->getIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE);
" next to the declaration of def and it is working fine.

Comment: @user3616535: very good - kindly approve my answer if it helped you. thanks.